# Why is my grid system only making a long column downwards and not across?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use the [thumbnail-custom example](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails-custom-content) from Bootstrap. However, my thumbnails are not being created across the window, only downwards. I want to make a a grid of 4 thumbnails across and 15 rows down. Eventually I want to make this scroll downwards infinitely, but I think I should probably start with getting a 4 x 15 grid first. What am I doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    

    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Adult Answers</title>

        <?php include('../config/js.php'); ?>

        <?php include('../config/css.php'); ?>



    </head>

    <body>

        <?php include('../template/navigation.php'); ?>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OcrRV00.jpg" alt="photogenic kitten">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>The cutest kitten in the world has no time for bubbles.</h3>
                        <p>What...</p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Pet him</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Don't pet him</a></p>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OcrRV00.jpg" alt="photogenic kitten">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>The cutest kitten in the world has no time for bubbles.</h3>
                        <p>What...</p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Pet him</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Don't pet him</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OcrRV00.jpg" alt="photogenic kitten">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>The cutest kitten in the world has no time for bubbles.</h3>
                        <p>What...</p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Pet him</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Don't pet him</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="container"> 
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OcrRV00.jpg" alt="photogenic kitten">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>The cutest kitten in the world has no time for bubbles.</h3>
                        <p>What...</p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Pet him</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Don't pet him</a></p>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OcrRV00.jpg" alt="photogenic kitten">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>The cutest kitten in the world has no time for bubbles.</h3>
                        <p>What...</p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Pet him</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Don't pet him</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OcrRV00.jpg" alt="photogenic kitten">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>The cutest kitten in the world has no time for bubbles.</h3>
                        <p>What...</p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Pet him</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Don't pet him</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OcrRV00.jpg" alt="photogenic kitten">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>The cutest kitten in the world has no time for bubbles.</h3>
                        <p>What...</p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Pet him</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Don't pet him</a></p>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OcrRV00.jpg" alt="photogenic kitten">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>The cutest kitten in the world has no time for bubbles.</h3>
                        <p>What...</p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Pet him</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Don't pet him</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OcrRV00.jpg" alt="photogenic kitten">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>The cutest kitten in the world has no time for bubbles.</h3>
                        <p>What...</p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Pet him</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Don't pet him</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>      

    </body>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
 form {
    max-width:500px;
    margin:50px auto;
  }
</style>
```

**JS**

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have `<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">` once for each of the three sets.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OcrRV00.jpg" alt="photogenic kitten">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>The cutest kitten in the world has no time for bubbles.</h3>
          <p>What...</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Pet him</a>  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Don't pet him</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OcrRV00.jpg" alt="photogenic kitten">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>The cutest kitten in the world has no time for bubbles.</h3>
          <p>What...</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Pet him</a>  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Don't pet him</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OcrRV00.jpg" alt="photogenic kitten">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>The cutest kitten in the world has no time for bubbles.</h3>
          <p>What...</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Pet him</a>  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Don't pet him</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```